# MCU Controlled JFET switch for negative voltage?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, switching, jfet

I have a JFET that requires negative voltage to the base in order to close and 0V to be open. I have the following power rails: 5V , -12V & GND (0V).

What would be the simplest way to switch the JFET's base between 0V & -12V using a GPIO pin from the MCU?

Answer (score 6):

You could tag a voltage divider off an PNP like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhrr6a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note Vcc shown above is expected to be 5V. If your logic output is at a lesser voltage you would need to recalculate R1 appropriately.

Or if ground needs to really be ground, the circuit below may be better. Note the control signal inversion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs5Fk7.png)</sup>

In both cases, you need to ensure Vhi of your output port is high enough to fully turn off the PNP transistor. If not, either use an open-collector output with a pull-up on the base, or drop the emitter voltage a little with a diode or two.

Comment: +1, but I suggest you to add an active low enable label in the first circuit, and active high enable label in the second circuit. Furthermore, even if the OP said that he has a 5V rail available, he did not say at which voltage the MCU is powered (it could be mounted on a board, which includes a 3.3V regulator, and the 3.3V is not brought externally). If the MCU has 3.3V GPIOs, then Q1 would be always on, I would add a note to this :)

Comment: Good points @next-hack

Answer (score 3):

I would use an optocoupler:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAPnzz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the GPIO is high, the optocoupler turns on and pulls the JFET gate to -12V. When the GPIO is low, optocoupler turns off and the resistor pulls the gate to 0V.

Cheap and simple. The LED resistor value will change depending on the optocoupler you choose. The JFET resistor value can be fairly high.

Comment: Notes for future readers: From my initial read of the question, I somehow thought that the voltages needed to be isolated. My bad. The transistor based solutions above are simpler for the non-isolated case.